# check value exists in JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

my JSON output is coming this way from API

```
var CityDistrictInfo = [{"classDesc":"FLOOD ZONE 11","classCode":"ZZ","legend":"011","districtName":"Fremont","atrSpaCityDistrictId":"a20cfe2b-51ed-4a11-8384-7fee393378ea","id":"00D18EECC47E7DF44200011302"},{"classDesc":"FLOOD ZONE 7 BONDS","classCode":"QE","legend":"007","districtName":"San Jose","atrSpaCityDistrictId":"a20cfe2b-51ed-4a11-8384-7fee393378ea","id":"00D18EECC47D86EA0E00011202"}]
```

Can any one please let me know how to validate the "districtName" in jQuery?. If I enter "Fremont" should return true or false.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you have single and a double quote around the legendIds array ?

Comment: `var legendIds = '"[00D18EECC4A1B4DBC000011202,00D18EECC4A1CCB9B400011202]"'` isn't what you want.

Comment: I am just trying diff scenarios with and with out single and double quotes

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`legendIDs` accepts an array of strings. So you should be specifying

```
var legendIds = ['00D18EECC4A1B4DBC000011202', '00D18EECC4A1CCB9B400011202']
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Any reason you down voted my answer?

Comment: Hey, Sorry I am recently started using stackoverflow. I am not sure how did it happend. Any way I googled and corrected :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Naren you are expected to both upvote and check off on the answer that you choose. So an upvote would also be nice on my answer :-)

Comment: Hi, one quick question about yesterday's post. I am trying to build the legends dynamically in javascript. Again I am getting "{"legendIDs":["The input was not valid."]}" error message. Please see below

Comment: for (i = 0; i < list.get_items().get_count() ; i++) 
{
 legendIds += "'" + list.getItem(i).get_value() + "'" + ",";
}
legendIds = legendIds.substring(0, legendIds.length - 1);
legendIds = '[' + legendIds + ']';

var cityDistrictId = 'fb7b7ecd-f8df-4591-89de-0c9ddcd217ef'
var atrDistrictLegend = { districtID: cityDistrictId, legendIDs: legendIds };
var test = JSON.stringify(atrDistrictLegend);

after test variable stringify: {"districtID":"fb7b7ecd-f8df-4591-89de-0c9ddcd217ef","legendIDs":"['00D18EECC4A1AE0F8600011202','00D18EECC47EAD76A400011302']"}
am i missing anything?

Comment: Hi @Naren I don't think you are escaping the quotes property. Can you paste the relevant code by editing your original question, so it is better formatted?

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/371392/web-user, I need your help. I got stuck in JSON validation.See below
my JSON output is coming this way from API

    var CityDistrictInfo = [{"classDesc":"FLOOD ZONE 11","classCode":"ZZ","legend":"011","districtName":"Fremont","atrSpaCityDistrictId":"a20cfe2b-51ed-4a11-8384-7fee393378ea","id":"00D18EECC47E7DF44200011302"}]

please let me know how to validate the "districtName" in jQuery?. If I enter "Fremont" should return true or false.

Comment: What do you mean by validate? If I have to take a guess, and if `jsonOutput` is the variable containing the output, `jsonOutput.districtName === 'Fremont'` should yield you a boolean value of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hi, my requirement is, when I am trying to insert the new "District". need to validate with existing districts whether district is available or not. So first place I am getting all the districts in JSON object and then validating the entered value. 
I tried above ur example. it's not working. Below is the JSON format
"[{\"cityDistrictName\":\"Oakland\",\"isActive\":\"N\",\"atrSpaClassLegends\":[],\"id\":\"499c435d-d77f-4f95-a677-1639a3b80e6e\"}]"

Comment: @Naren so do you need to iterate multiple objects in a JSON represented array, where one of the objects' `districtName` attribute value is `Fremont`? If that is the case, you could do this: `!!CityDistrictInfo.find(function(cityDistrict) { return cityDistrict.districtName === 'Fremont'; })`. What this code does is iterate through your `CityDistrictInfo` array list and returns the first match. I am using the `!!` operator, so it converts the return value of the `Array.prototype.find()` method into `true` or `false`. Hope this helps.